# Visualise variance partitioning

Tags: r, data-visualization, variance, partitioning

I'm interested in visualising variance partitioning in the context of linear models. Say you run an linear regression that predicts peoples weight based on their height and age. How can you visualise the amount of the variation in people's weight that is explained by their height, the amount of variation that is explained by their weight and the amount of variation that is unexplained?

Comment: If you are interested only in `R` solutions, then this thread is off-topic here.  It would be on-topic if you would re-focus it on *how* to visualize variance partitioning.  If you make that edit, then could you please elaborate on what you mean by "variance partitioning" and the intended context in which it would be applied?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easy to do in 2-dimensional case. Draw a unit box. Inside the box draw overlapping two boxes: for height and age. The size of the inside boxes would be proportional to the portion of the variance explained by each variable, while the area of the overlap would be accounting for correlation between the age and weight. The remaining space inside the box would be the error variance portion.

Here's the linear model: $$y=X\beta+\varepsilon$$ so we have the variance: $$\sigma^2_y=VarCov[X]\beta+\sigma^2_\varepsilon$$
$$\frac{VarCov[X]\beta}{\sigma^2_y}+\frac{\sigma^2_\varepsilon}{\sigma^2_y}$$
So the boxes have the following areas inside the unit box: $\frac{Var[x_{height}]}{\sigma^2_{y}}$, $\frac{Var[x_{age}]}{\sigma^2_y}$ and $\frac{\sigma^2_\varepsilon}{\sigma^2_y}$

The overlap area between height and age boxes is: $\frac{Cov[x_{height},x_{age}]}{\sigma^2_{y}}$

Comment: Aksakal - are you able to actually draw the boxes?

Comment: It should be easy to draw them in R using line commands. This forum is not for code problems, btw.